# How to use a web disk with encrypted volumes?

Tags: encryption, webdav

I want to use a web disk whose access is available via WebDAV, but I want to put the information encrypted (using for example the encrypted .dmg file in osx). As far as I understand, this has the drawback that any modification requires the whole file to be transferred between the machines via WebDAV.

Is this true? Does any of you have an alternative nice solution on how to use a web disk with encrypted volumes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is true.  However, unless I am mistaken, I believe that the same is true for WebDAV, so that will not solve your problem.  If you had an unencrypted .dmg file stored on your WebDAV server and changed just one file, you would still need to transfer the entire .dmg to update it.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use the WebDAV share over HTTP, and make sure the data is actually encrypted on the server, rather than on your client.

This can only be done if you have control over the server though..